# How can I create an endpoint for yolov5 inference in AWS sagemaker

Tags: python, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, yolov5

I've trained yolov5 to detect a custom object, now I have to deploy it on AWS sagemaker, for that I need to create an endpoint for inference, I've seen some tutorials on how to create endpoints on AWS but I don't know how to do it for yolov5 , can someone help me please ?

Comment: Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a model such as yolov5 on SageMaker, you will need to build a custom container, this approach is known as Bring Your Own Container (BYOC). You will need to install yolov5 on the Dockerfile and adopt your inference code in the predictor.py file. Take a look at the following example with the library Spacy, you can mimic everything except the Dockerfile and predictor.py which you need to adjust for installation and your inference code logic.

BYOC Example: https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/BYOC/PreTrained-Examples/SpacyNER

Files To Adjust: Dockerfile , predictor.py

Comment: Thank you for your response, from what I have understood, I replace the Dockerfile by the yolov5's Dockerfile and predictor.py by the yolov5's resapi.py ?

Comment: While Ram's answer is correct, I think it would be easier to use the SageMaker inference toolkit: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit

Comment: @GiliNachum can you elaborate more please.

Comment: The SageMaker Inference Toolkit implements a model serving stack and can be easily added to any Docker container, making it deployable to SageMaker. 
Just read the background section here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit

Comment: From what I have understood all I need to do is replacing the docker file in the container by the yolov5's docker file ?